# Pass dropdown values to javascript function and store them as array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html-select

I have a javascript function in this function I have to pass multiple dropdown selected values and store these values into a javascript array.
when I select a value from one dropdown box and I send this values using onchange() function then it will store into javascript array then after when I select another dropdown values then it also stores into the same javascript array.
I want to display javascript alert box when same value is store more than one time into that array, just like validation.
for this, i already created a simple javascript function when i pass one selected values using onChange event it store into array , but second time when i do same thing then first values has eleminated from array and another values has stored.

I want to store all selected values into that array and compare it if the value is repeat or not ?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make your array global and write functions under the variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
var items= [];  //Define the array globally

//element is nothing but dropdown value that need to be passed from each dropdown
function checkRepeat(element) {
    items.push(element);  //add element to items array
    var j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      for (j=i+1; j < items.length;j++) {

    var n = items[i].localeCompare(items[j]);  //compare each item 
    if (n == 0) {  //n will become 0 when values are same
    alert("items are repeated..");
    }
    }

    }

}
</script>
```